# javascript private variables access problem

Tags: javascript, plugins, frameworks, closures

this one for the javascript gurus:

I'm experimenting with a new javascript framework. Its structure is inspired by none other than the mighty jQuery.

It has a global variable called `$j`, and .. oh, just see it in action:

```
/* file: jfoo.js */
$j = new (function(){
    var modules=[];
    this.loadModule = function(mod) {
        modules[ modules.length ] = mod;
    }
    this.hasModule = function(mod) {
        for( ind in modules )
            if( modules[ind]==mod ) return true;
        return false;
    }
})();
```

You see that modules is a private variable. No problem; that just what I intended.

Now, I want to write a plugin that adds a `$j.loadBatch` method to my system. So..

```
/* file: loadBatch.jfoo.js */
!$j || (function(){
    $j.loadBatch = function(batch) {
         for(ind in batch)
             modules[ modules.length++ ] = batch[ind];
     }
})();
```

But, since this method is not part of the closure in file `jfoo.js`, this is not possible.

I also tried this version:

```
/* file: jfoo.js */
$j = new (function(){
    var modules=[];
    this.loadModule = function(mod) {
        modules[ modules.length ] = mod;
    }
    this.hasModule = function(mod) {
        for( ind in modules )
            if( modules[ind]==mod ) return true;
        return false;
    }
    this.extend = function(extensions) {
        for( ext in extensions )
            this[ext] = extensions[ext];
    }
})();
```

and

```
/* file:loadBatch.jfoo.js */
!$j || (function(){
    $j.extend( {
        loadBatch : function(batch) {
            for(ind in batch)
                modules[ modules.length++ ] = batch[ind];
        }
    });
})();
```

But I got no better results.

So, the questions:

- Is there any way that I can write the `loadBatch` method in a separate file and still have it access the private method `modules`? (I expect the answer to be a resounding NO, but, who knows?)
- is there any other way by which I can achive the desired effect without making `modules` public? (I know how to proceed if I make it public)
- does jQuery use private members? how does it get over its "private accessibility" problems then?

Thanks,

jrh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to give access to a "private" variable (variable only within the scope of a closure) to some execution contexts outside its scope, but not others. (e.g. you could write an accessor method but couldn't limit who gets access)

Comment: any idea how jQuery does it? Does jQuery actually do it?

Comment: jQuery uses a build step to glue all the files together into one before sending to the client.